# NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(ExampleModule)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: NullInjectorError: No provider for Router

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular-test

I am preparing a unit test case for AppComponent which has a router as an injected dependency and have included RouterTestingModule in my test bed.
Still getting errors. Please find the error log shown below:

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RouterLinkWithHref -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'RouterLinkWithHref', Function ], ngDebugContext: DebugContext_({ view: Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 33669121, rootNodeFlags: 33554433, nodeMatchedQueries: 0, flags: 0, nodes: [ Object({ nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 33554433, childFlags: 114688, directChildFlags: 114688, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object({  }), matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object({  }), ngContentIndex: null, childCount: 1, bindings: [  ], bindingFlags: 0, outputs: [  ], element: Object({ ns: '', name: 'app-forgot-password', attrs: [  ], template: null, componentProvider: Object({ nodeIndex: 1, parent: <circular reference: Object>, renderParent: <circular reference: Object>, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 1, flags: 114688, childFlags: 0, directChildFlags: 0, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object, matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object,  ...
    at <Jasmine>
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:855:1)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17514:1)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17440:1)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17266:1)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17514:1)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17440:1)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:17266:1)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:30393:1)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:31578:1)
    at resolveDep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:32143:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, just i imported this in the component.spec.ts file.

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
```

and

```
 imports: [
   ------>
        RouterTestingModule //add this in the imports section  <-------
      ]
```